# sns.factorplot separate charts

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to create factorplots for values from one column with 18 values and I'm adding hue parameters as a different column also with 18 unique values, this results in huge chart that is not easy to read. So I want to create separate charts for every unique value from the column so that it's more clearly visible.
So currently it looks like this:
[factorplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zau2R.png)

And I want to split those 18 charts divided by hue into separate charts. 
I was thinking of using loop but I'm stuck at this point:

```
for i in dframe.type1.unique():
    sns.factorplot(x='type1',data=dframe, kind='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `col` parameter. Check out more examples on the [seaborn doc page for factorplots](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html) about 2/3 of the way down.

```
sns.factorplot(x='type1', col='type2', col_wrap=4, data=dframe, kind='count',
               sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however there is one more thing. The labels for x are displayed only for the last of the separate charts, I tried to fix it with f.set_xticklabels(['Poison', 'Flying', 'Ground', 'Fairy', 'Grass', 'Fighting',
       'Psychic', 'Steel', 'Ice', 'Rock', 'Water', 'Electric', 'Fire',
       'Dragon', 'Dark', 'Ghost', 'Bug', 'Normal'])

Comment: I modified the statement to not share x or y axis. This will make each subplot independent of the other and ensure that labels exist for all x values.

Comment: `g=sns.factorplot(x='type1', col='type2', col_wrap=3, data=dframe, kind='count', sharex=False, sharey=False, palette=pokemon_color_palette)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(60)
        
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.15, hspace=.4)`
So this is my code and last thing I want to do is to increase spacing between every xticklabel, whats the best way I can do this? And is there a better way to adjust the spacing between subplots than the way I did? Thanks a lot for you help!